# Why are some sculpt brush thumbnails grayed out?

Tags: sculpting

I just noticed that in Sculpt mode, when you click on the big brush button in the tool shelf to select the brush type, some of the brushes are shown with color and some without color:

[image: brush types]

First I thought I had messed up my sculpt settings and tried to adjust them so that all brush types are shown with color. But then I saw that the thumbnails look exactly the same in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools.html).

Could it be that there's some deeper reason for the different coloring? Or is this really just some random UI inconsistency?

Comment: What do you mean by "grayed out"? The gray color doesn't indicate that they are deactivated. It's just their normal appearance. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools.html

Comment: @metaphor_set: "grayed out" may have been an unfortunate word choice. I just mean "without color".